# Can you get good code from Anima in Sketch?

Tags: export

I have a twofold type question regarding Anima's export to code feature in Sketch.
As a designer it's tempting to think of your work straight to code but, the reality is it doesn't quite work like that.

So, the first part of my question is: how good/reliable you think that code is?
The second part is an ask for help with the code.

So, I've created this super simple 2-page random quote generator in Sketch to call out bullshit on the President of Brazil (the crap the guy says...). I designed 3 breakpoints and all that but now that the code is here, I don't know how to do simple things like adding links to the buttons.

Plus, when you click the big green button on the homepage you should be taken to the results.html where a .js is going to generate a sentence. 
The .js is ready to go.
Here's the prototype link: https://winter-glade-8944.animaapp.io

Comment: Hey, we don't often answer questions like this on SO. There are multiple problems with it and it's likely to get closed. You'll need to ask a single question per post, and you'll need to show us some sample code to go by -- we don't all have access to Sketch (whatever that is). Also, try adding tags, and what you've tried.

Answer (score -1):

Anima is already in its first age , the big problem that most of time , it will **be stuck in one page , and you can't get the code of other pages** ,
the best solution is to duplicate your project on Figma , then extract the first page's code , then delete this page from anime , then generate the code for the second page ,, and so on